# how to change table specific column width in HTML?

Tags: html, css

i have this below table.and i want to change a specific column width=>by changing its default width.previously i have done that.but now on this below table its not working for me.i dont know why.

i want to change those column where i add width:400px;
i know css expert can help me about this.please help.i have a very little knowledge in css.

```css
.namex {
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div class="namex">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Full Name
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Profile Pic
            </th>
            <th style="width:400px;">
                Currently Assigned Courses
            </th>
            <th width="200px">
                Currently Assigned Batches
            </th>
            <th>
                Company Name
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
            <th>
                Phone Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Email Address
            </th>
            <th>
                Zip Code
            </th>
            <th>
                User Nationality
            </th>
            <th>
                Gender
            </th>
            <th>
                Religion
            </th>
            <th>
                Blood Group
            </th>
            <th>
                Date Of Birth
            </th>
            <th>
                User Activation Date
            </th>
            <th>
                User Current Status
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    md.amjad hossain
                </td>
                <td>
                    md.amjad
                </td>
                <td>
                    hossain
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="/Content/img/tsms/default/owner.jpg" height="80" width="80" style="border-radius:2px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select onchange="alert(this.value)" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="CCNA Security">CCNA Security</option>
                                <option value="Oracle Database 12c">Oracle Database 12c</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select onchange="alert(this.value)" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="CCNA Security-1">CCNA Security-1</option>
                                <option value="Oracle Database 12c-1">Oracle Database 12c-1</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    aiub
                </td>
                <td>
                    dhaka
                </td>
                <td>
                    1830954149
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="mailto:nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com">nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    1362
                </td>
                <td>
                    bangladeshi
                </td>
                <td>
                    male
                </td>
                <td>
                    islam
                </td>
                <td>
                    o+
                </td>
                <td>
                    2/25/1995
                </td>
                <td>
                    5/8/2017
                </td>
                <td>
                    Active
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Students/Edit/2">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="/Students/Details/2">Details</a> |
                    <a href="/Students/Delete/2">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>

in my case its look like ---

[![Pic of my table][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Dr0.png

look 
 
        <th style="width:400px;">
            Currently Assigned Courses
        </th>
        <th width="200px">
            Currently Assigned Batches
        </th>

is not working after applying width.its still look like 0px.
thats my problem.
```

[image: Pic of my table]
    look

```
        <th style="width:400px;">
            Currently Assigned Courses
        </th>
        <th width="200px">
            Currently Assigned Batches
        </th>
```

is not working after applying width.its still look like 0px.
thats my problem.

Comment: Could you be more specific and tell us exactly what's your problem? which column you want to change its width?

Comment: By seeing your code, you have tried setting it in two columns namely, `Currently Assigned Courses` and `Currently Assigned Batches`, which one is not rendering properly in your code?

Comment: This is because `<td>` and `<th>` are by default `display: table-cell`(UserAgent styles). If you change them to for example `display: block`, the width will take effect

Comment: By the way the `width` attribute of `<th>` is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead - `<th style="width:400px;">` is fine

Answer (score 4):

You should check out the `colgroup` elements. Instead of specifying widths on table headers, specify the required size on the `col` tags.

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
       <col>
       <col style="width: 100px">
       <!-- repeat as many cols as the number of headers -->
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
       <tr>
       <th> Header 1 </th>
           <th> Header 2 </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td> DAta 1 </td>
           <td> Data 2 </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here what if you do not specify anything inside col tag, it will behave as browser default.
Well as per w3schools

> The `<col>` tag specifies column properties for each column within a  element.
>
> The `<col>` tag is useful for applying styles to entire columns, instead of repeating the styles for each cell, for each row.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a table width, by default the browser sets the table with at 100% of its with, and will try to fit all tds within that with, if you want to use a specific width, you need to also set a specific width of the table.

```
.table { width:1000px; }
```

just make sure that the width is enough to accomodate any padding, margins, or borders + text.

The specific widths you set for any td will not exceed the set width, but could still shrink smaller if you do not allow for sufficient total table width

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the width of specific columns, you can always assign a class to that column, then it's a matter of styling that column through CSS.
You'll also need to use `!important` to override any `width` property that has been assigned to that particular column. more about `!important`  rule here : [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

The following is an example, you can use it as start guide.

```css
.namex {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.width-lg {
    width: 400px !important;
}
.width-md {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="namex">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Full Name
      </th>
      <th>
        First Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Last Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Profile Pic
      </th>
      <th class="width-lg">
        Currently Assigned Courses
      </th>
      <th class="width-md">
        Currently Assigned Batches
      </th>
      <th>
        Company Name
      </th>
      <th>
        City
      </th>
      <th>
        Phone Number
      </th>
      <th>
        Email Address
      </th>
      <th>
        Zip Code
      </th>
      <th>
        User Nationality
      </th>
      <th>
        Gender
      </th>
      <th>
        Religion
      </th>
      <th>
        Blood Group
      </th>
      <th>
        Date Of Birth
      </th>
      <th>
        User Activation Date
      </th>
      <th>
        User Current Status
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        md.amjad hossain
      </td>
      <td>
        md.amjad
      </td>
      <td>
        hossain
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="/Content/img/tsms/default/owner.jpg" height="80" width="80" style="border-radius:2px;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange="alert(this.value)" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="CCNA Security">CCNA Security</option>
                                <option value="Oracle Database 12c">Oracle Database 12c</option>

                    </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select onchange="alert(this.value)" class="form-control input-lg">
                                <option value="CCNA Security-1">CCNA Security-1</option>
                                <option value="Oracle Database 12c-1">Oracle Database 12c-1</option>

                    </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        aiub
      </td>
      <td>
        dhaka
      </td>
      <td>
        1830954149
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="mailto:nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com">nayanchowdhury92@gmail.com</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        1362
      </td>
      <td>
        bangladeshi
      </td>
      <td>
        male
      </td>
      <td>
        islam
      </td>
      <td>
        o+
      </td>
      <td>
        2/25/1995
      </td>
      <td>
        5/8/2017
      </td>
      <td>
        Active
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/Students/Edit/2">Edit</a> |
        <a href="/Students/Details/2">Details</a> |
        <a href="/Students/Delete/2">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```